# Limit Question involving infinite multiplication?

Tags: calculus, limits

$$\lim_{n\to ∞} \prod_{i=1}^n ({n+i\over n})^{1\over n} $$

For this question I tried using the substitution

$$ u = {1\over n}$$

So as "n" goes to infinity, "u" goes towards zero. So the limit changes to:

$$\lim_{u\to 0} ((1+u)(1+2u)...(2-2u)(2-u)(2))^{u}$$

So my thinking was that since the terms inside are being raised to the "u" power and "u" is getting infinitely close to 0 the limit should tend towards 1.

But according to Wolfram Alpha

$$\lim_{n\to ∞} \prod_{i=1}^n ({n+i\over n})^{1\over n} = {4\over e} $$

I'm not sure how they ended up with that answer and was hoping that someone can help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem in this case is, that the number of factors increase with $n$, so you can't argue in this way. In a similar fashion the sequence $1 = \sum \limits_{i = 1}^n \frac{1}{n}$ does not converge to $0$.

Instead, you can take the logarithm of your product:

$$\ln \left(\prod \limits_{i = 1}^n \left( \frac{i + n}{n}\right)^\frac{1}{n} \right) = \sum \limits_{i = 1}^n \frac{1}{n}\ln \left(1 + \frac{i}{n}\right)$$

Now you can interpte this term as a Riemann-sum and calculate its limit as $\int_0^1 \log(1 + x) \; dx = \ln(4) - 1$. Applying the exponential function now yields the limit of the original sequence.

Comment: Do you mind explaining how after taking the natural logarithm of the function. Exponent "n" became "1/n" shouldn't it just be multiplied by the ln(1 +i/n)?

Comment: My bad, it should be $\frac{1}{n}$ in the first place. I'll correct it.

Comment: Do you mind explaining how you got from the summation to the integral?

Comment: This follows directly from the definition of the Riemann-integral via Riemann-sums.

Comment: Again, this follows directly from the *definition* of the Riemann-integral. Please take a look into any calculus book, the theory of riemann-integrals is too extensive to write down into a comment.

Comment: I disagree with "The problem in this case is, that the number of factors increase with n, so you can't argue in this way". There is nothing wrong with the fact that there are an infinite number of factors (or summands). The problem is that this is an expression of the form $f(n)^{g(n)}$ where $g(n)\to 0$ and $f(n)\to\infty$, which is an indeterminate form. If $f(n)$ had an infinite number of factors but a finite limit, the argument would work.

Comment: Or, on a more fundamental level, the problem is @user262291 trying to evaluate the limit informally without resorting to a known result/theorem such as "if $f(x)\to M$ and $g(x)\to N$, then $f(x)g(x)\to MN$" (which should be taught with a proper discussion on what an "indeterminate form" is).

Comment: @FedericoPoloni: What Dominik mentions in his answer is the exact reason why the technique used by OP fails. OP is trying to use the product rule for limits which is valid only when the number of factors used is independent of the limiting variable. Here $n$ is the number of factors and $n$ is also the limit variable. There is a special theorem called monotone convergence theorem (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_convergence_theorem) which applies to the case of "sum rule for limits" (taking logs product is reduced to sum) but even that is not applicable here.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni: I aslo think that you are putting too much focus on indeterminate form. The product rule of limits has nothing do with such forms. If $f(x) \to M$ and $g(x) \to N$ then $f(x)g(x) \to MN$ where $M, N$ are real numbers. I don't see how indeterminate forms comes into picture here.